# Using Time datatype in MySQL without seconds

Tags: mysql, time, types

I'm trying to store a 12/24hr (ie; 00:00) clock time in a MySQL database. At the moment I am using the time datatype. This works ok but it insists on adding the seconds to the column. So you enter 09:20 and it is stored as 09:20:00. Is there any way I can limit it in MySQL to just 00:00?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That doesn't look possible. The [`TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time.html) data type is defined to represent the time of the day (or elapsed time) with a 1 second resolution. However, you can always use the [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to format your field as `HH:MM` in a `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%k:%i');
+-----------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%k:%i') |
+-----------------------------+
| 4:09                        |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i');
+-----------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i') |
+-----------------------------+
| 04:09                       |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`TIME` column type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html) does not accept any parameter or modifier to define range or precision. You can, however, omit seconds on insert if you are careful:

> Be careful about assigning abbreviated values to a TIME column. MySQL
>   interprets abbreviated TIME values with colons as time of the day.
>   That is, **'11:12' means '11:12:00', not '00:11:12'**. MySQL interprets
>   abbreviated values without colons using the assumption that the two
>   rightmost digits represent seconds (that is, as elapsed time rather
>   than as time of day). For example, you might think of **'1112' and 1112**
>   as meaning '11:12:00' (12 minutes after 11 o'clock), but MySQL
>   **interprets them as '00:11:12'** (11 minutes, 12 seconds). Similarly,
>   '12' and 12 are interpreted as '00:00:12'.

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    example_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    elapsed TIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (example_id)
);
INSERT INTO example (elapsed) VALUES ('123:45:00'), ('123:45');
SELECT * FROM example;
```

```
+------------+-----------+
| example_id | elapsed   |
+------------+-----------+
|          1 | 123:45:00 |
|          2 | 123:45:00 |
+------------+-----------+
```

... and you can remove them on read (if necessary) by applying a proper [TIME_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format), noting that:

> If the time value contains an hour part that is greater than 23, the
>   %H and %k hour format specifiers produce a value larger than the usual
>   range of 0..23. The other hour format specifiers produce the hour
>   value modulo 12.

```
INSERT INTO example (elapsed) VALUES ('2:00');
SELECT example_id, TIME_FORMAT(elapsed, '%k:%i') AS elapsed
FROM example;
```

```
+------------+---------+
| example_id | elapsed |
+------------+---------+
|          1 | 123:45  |
|          2 | 123:45  |
|          3 | 2:00    |
+------------+---------+
```

Since MySQL/5.7.5 you can also use a [generated column](http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/) to get a display value automatically:

```
-- Completely untested, I don't have 5.7 yet
CREATE TABLE example (
    example_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    elapsed TIME NOT NULL,
    -- Size to accomodate for '-838:59:59'
    elapsed_display VARCHAR(10) AS (TIME_FORMAT(elapsed, '%k:%i')) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (example_id)
);
```